# How to give PHP variable to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am searching for a better way to send my PHP variable to Javascript. Currently I echo the variable in PHP:

```js
<script>
  var numbers = <?php echo $numbers ?>;
</script>
```

I then access this variable in Javascript like this: `class.method(numbers);`

My PHP file is included in the index.php before the javascript file, so I have access to this variable in the javascript file.

Now I am looking for a nicer way to submit the PHP variable than using `echo`. Does anyone have an idea?

The output of numbers looks like:

[image]

Comment: Actually, you should not mix JS and PHP at all. If you need data on a page, fetch it with AJAX, or include it in a script tag with an appropriate type attribute.

Comment: Maybe a hidden field where the value is the php variable and then you may retrieve the field value with javascript

Comment: @Rory McCrossan How can I attach data to HTML in the smartest way, because in my opinion I have to do it also with echo, because HTML does not know the PHP variables.

Comment: @ChristianTeubner I added an answer for you below

Comment: @Teemu I agree with you completely. I removed my comments as they could be misconstrued.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Though manipulating JS with PHP is a very commonly used practice ( is delicious, millions of flies can't be wrong, can they?), I've started to advice against it. You can imagine a fresh developer failing their first security audit, and then them explaining "But I got the code from SO ..." The dev won't feel very comfortable, and it's also bad promotion to SO too. I know I've already lost the war, but still continuing the battle, maybe we needed a canonical answer to this question, and use it like [this dup target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429) ..?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mix your php with JS .the one you have used is better .also you can try something like this
Add a display none span to your html page with id :document_target
example

```
<span id="document_target" style="display: none;"><?=$numbers;?></span>
```

in js file get data of span with id

```
 var myNumber = document.getElementById("document_target").textContent;
```

Comment: This is correct way to "inject" PHP into JS. Appending PHP variable to HTML make it work as a template which is just a dynamic generated HTML code and such code shall be used by JS.

Answer (score 1):

One better alternative would be to output the PHP value to a `data` attribute. Given that this variable doesn't seem to be tied to a specific element, you could put it at root level on the `body` element. Then you can read it from there when the JS executes once the DOM has loaded, like this:

```html
<body data-numbers="<?php echo $numbers ?>">
   <!-- your HTML ... -->
</body>
```

```js
let numbers = document.body.dataset.numbers; // plain JS

let numbers = $('body').data('numbers'); // jQuery
```

This is under the assumption that the `$numbers` variable in your PHP is holding a value which can be coerced to a string

-- *Update* --

Given the edit to your question where you clarify that `$numbers` in fact contains an object, you can instead encode it to JSON, output it to a `<script>` tag and then use it from there:

```html
<script type="text/plain" id="numbers">
   <?= $json_encode($numbers) ?>
</script>
```

```js
let numbers = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#numbers').textContent.trim()); // plain JS

let numbers = JSON.parse($('#numbers').text().trim()); // jQuery
```

Comment: I tried it and when I do it the same way, it doesn't work. Numbers is an object, however when I then want to access numbers in JS numbers is just { .

Comment: In that case can you please edit the question to show exactly what the output of `<?php echo $numbers ?>` looks like

Comment: I have added the picture

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline script tag to add data to the HTML document like this:

```js
const dataElement = document.querySelector('#phpData'),
  data = JSON.parse(dataElement.text);
  
console.log(data.example, data.number);
```

```html
<!-- This tag is what really is rendered on the page -->
<script type="text/plain" id="phpData">
{
  "example": "Example string",
  "number": 10
}
</script>

<!-- This tag is written in the source code of the page -->
<script type="text/plain" id="phpData">
{
  "someValue": <?=$some_value?>,
  "otherValue": <?=$other_value?>
}
</script>
```

As can be seen, when running the example, the script with inappropriate JS type attribute is not executed.

In that script tag you can echo variables or other values as you need (like in the latter example), or even echo a `json_encode`d string. This is one of the safest way to include PHP variables to JS, and you can still save your actual JavaScript into an external file. The data script must be included in the HTML document, because you can't access .js files with PHP, and also, for security reasons, JS can't read `text` from an external file.

What comes to the usage of `echo`, it's a PHP language construct specifically meant to add content to the markup, there's no reason to avoid it. I've used a short hand of [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) in the latter example, but it still is `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to do this:

1. Get the values from the form fields if there's a form, or whatever and send them in a query to php from JS, this work regardless where the php file is, it can be a remote file on a different server, or just another local page,etc.
2. The php file receives the request and reply back
3. retrieve the reply of the php file in the JS.

An example of the above using jquery:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit_button").change(function(){
                var my_id = "some value here, or do some getelement by id .val()..."
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'includes/forms.php', //or replace with a remote url
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {  some_requestPHP_name: my_id } //note this line
                }).done(function(data){
                    console.log(`js got from php =${data}` )
                    //
                      var numbers = data;

                    
                })
            })
        })
```

Now in the php file you need to make the file react whenever it recieves something containing the line I indicated above  containing `some_requestPHP_name`, this is a parameter that you decide

```
if (isset($_POST["some_requestPHP_name"]))  echo  some_function(); // you can use the "some_requestPHP_name" just as a trigger to call the some_function of you can use the data from it

function some_function(){
// do things and return the number;
return 1;
}
```

Depending on your usage you may not have a form/button etc so you may want to remove the .change() and execute the function right away, at this point it's up to you to adapt the example to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it like this:

```
<script src="./assets/scripts/tableActions.js"></script> <!-- JS SCRIPT -->
<table class="w-full" id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th class='border-b p-2 w-52 border-gray-400'>Full Name</th><th class='border-b border-l p-2 w-52 border-gray-400'>Username</th><th class='p-2 border-l border-b w-36 border-gray-400'>Role</th><th class='p-2 border-l border-b border-gray-400'>E-mail</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    include('./functions/connectSQL.php');
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    $x = 1;
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        
                        echo "<tr class='hover:bg-gray-800 cursor-pointer' onClick='returnValues(".$x.");' id='tableRow'><td class='border-t p-2 px-4 border-gray-400' id='fullnameCell'>" .$row["fullname"]  . "</td><td class='border-l border-t p-2 px-4 border-gray-400' id='usernameCell'>".$row["username"]."</td><td class='border-l border-t p-2 px-4 border-gray-400' id='roleCell'>" . $row["role"] . "</td><td class='border-l border-t p-2 px-4 border-gray-400' id='emailCell'>" . $row["email"] . "</td></tr>";
                        $x++;
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

See, that `onClick='returnValues(".$x.");'` have inside itself variable from PHP. So you will give varibale to javascript using function. Now it is like you probably know:

```
function returnValues(x){
    const table = document.querySelector('table');
    const cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');
    const values = Array.from(cells).map(cell => cell.innerText);
    var tableRow = document.getElementById("table").rows;
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    const usernameField = document.getElementById('usernameForm');
    for (i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++){
        let tableCells = tableRow[x].cells[i].innerHTML;
        form.elements[i].value = tableCells;
    }

    if(values.includes(usernameField.innerText)){
        formButtonAdmin.innerText = "Update";
    }
}
```

Now you could be good, when you will have any other questions, feel free to ask :D
Have a nice day!

Comment: This is just one more "_fly_", inline event listeners are equally bad practice like PHP and JS mixing.